# Symfony2.0.15 Doctrine-Fixtures Windows Command Line Fatal Error

Tags: php, windows, symfony, doctrine-orm

Recently started playing around with S2, amazing stuff! A while ago started an online Symfony2 [Blog tutorial](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/doctrine-2-the-blog-model.html), however I got stuck on the page with Doctrine Data Fixtures generation,

Here is the message I'm getting when executing `php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load` in the console:

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Command\DoctrineCommand' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog-sf2\vendor\bundles\Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Command\LoadDataFixturesDoctrineCommand.php on line 40

I am really stuck on it and I am running **Windows 7**, so can't really use deps file to pull dependencies from older versions (OR CAN I somehow??),

I've downloaded the newest versions of FixtureBundles and DoctrineFixtures.

Really appreciate any help on this one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to read [the installation documentation of this bundle for the 2.0 branch](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)
You don't really "use the deps" file. The bin/vendors script uses it, and uses git. So what you need to do to "use the deps" is install git (and btw, install git-bash, you'll get a far better terminal).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I am actually using Cygwin so will need to install Git (found instructions so it will be ok) and will let you know about the results tomorrow (and thanks for that link, I will follow it as soon as I get Git up and running)

Comment: The fixtures are working properly,
first step was to include:
`[doctrine-fixtures]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures.git

[DoctrineFixturesBundle]
    git=http://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/DoctrineFixturesBundle
    version=origin/2.0`
in the deps file, and then if on Windows install Git.
Then run `php bin/vendors install --reinstall` from the console, update autoload and appKernel and here we go, all working FINE! THANKS!